# Redis zrange ignore key word order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

I am using redis to store and display my search suggestions in my rails app. It works perfectly except for one thing. Lets's say I have a user named John Doe. It will suggest him if the user searches for John, but not if he searches for Doe.

How can I write my code so it would ignore the word order of my input?

Here is how I get my terms from the redis database now:

```
$redis.zrevrange "search-suggestions:#{prefix}", 0, 5
```

Comment: For now I resolved my issue by just indexing the user twice. Once with "first_name last_name" and once with "last_name first_name". I would still prefer to index the user just once and search without word order

Comment: You did correctly - if you want a 2-way search, you'll need two sets or double the members like you have.